# Символ с HEX кодом 0А

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть PHP-файл, который создаёт xml-файл

```
print '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>';
```

Раньше он создавал его нормально, первая строка файла на выходе была:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
```

теперь (возможно, с обновлением сервера или ещё чего) первая срока пустая и файл начинается со второй, в HEX-редакторе видно, что пустая строка делается символом 0A, раньше в создаваемом файле его не было. От чего такое может произойти?

**Дополнено.**

Перед строкой print имеется следующий код:

```
function ExportCML($order_id)
{
if (!int($order_id)) return false;

$this->LoadOrder($order_id);
$this->CartContents();

// работает только если один и тот же "каталог товаров" в 1С
list($ext_company_id, $ext_catalogue_id) = explode(" ",
value1("SELECT external_id
      FROM Netshop_ImportSources 
      WHERE source_id='".$this->CartContents[0]["ImportSourceID"]."'"));

header("Content-Type: Aplication/xml-file");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order{$this->OrderID}.xml");
```

Comment: Перед строкой print имеется следующий код:
   function ExportCML($order_id)
   {
    if (!int($order_id)) return false;

    $this->LoadOrder($order_id);
    $this->CartContents();

    // работает только если один и тот же "каталог товаров" в 1С
    list($ext_company_id, $ext_catalogue_id) = explode(" ",
    value1("SELECT external_id
          FROM Netshop_ImportSources 
          WHERE source_id='".$this->CartContents[0]["ImportSourceID"]."'"));

    header("Content-Type: Aplication/xml-file");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=order{$this->OrderID}.xml");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог только HEX редактор. В нем удалил этот рабочий КОД. Читал про него, что он является меткой для кодировки, но вот что именно делает, второй раз найти не могу.
P.S. Нашел, вероятнее всего это связано с BOM (Byte Order Mark) для кодировки UTF-8.
Но почему вначале файла только один символ перевода каретки, так и не понял.

Comment: Ни в одной кодировке Unicode последовательность кодирующая BOM не содержит 0x0A. Не туда копаете. У вас просто символ перевода строки, ищите код, который его добавляет. Заголовки HTTP от тела отделяются пустой строкой, возможно там лишний перевод впечатывается.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно в начале файла перед `<?php` или `<?` стоит лишний перевод строки, проверьте самое начало вашего файла

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, перед созданием заголовка XML файла есть уже вывод в файл - нужно смотреть код выше данной строки.